# Is it useful to provide a type-safe method?

Tags: java, interface, casting

I'm designing the interface as follows:

```
public interface Parameters {

    public <T> T getValue(ParameterName pn, Class<T> valueType) throws ClassCastException;
}
```

An implementation is obligated to throw `ClassCastException` if the `Class` instance of the value to be returned is not an [assignableForm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) of the `Class` passed as a parameter.

Does it make sesnse? It provides compile-time type-safety, but we can do the same with just explicit cast.

Or it's much better to declare just

```
public Object getValue(ParameterName pn)
```

leaving all class-cast issues to the client.

Comment: In this case I do not see much difference between the approaches. Type mismatches will be only found at runtime in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this form of API where I add the ability to convert the type to the one desired. e.g. if it's a String but you need an Integer it will attempt to parse it.

Otherwise, as you suggest you are not adding much that this method doesn't provide.

```
 public <T> T getValue(ParameterName pn);
```

This avoid needing an explicit cast.

Comment: I think your example shows a bad solution because for the client it hides the fact that `getValue` might return a type which is different from the expected. In that case they will end up with a very unexpected `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @Lii Good point, it rather depends on what you are trying to achieve. Having to specify the type as a cast every time would be more explicit but also possibly a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

It is a misunderstanding that you gain any compile-time type-safety by passing the `Class` object of the expected return type as a parameter. If the client passes a `Class` of the wrong type the error will only get detected at runtime.

But I think the design with a `Class` parameter has other advantages:

- The parameters creates a natural place to document the behaviour of the method regarding the return type.
- You can write code in the method to check the `Class` parameter and provide a specific and meaningful error message if the user makes a mistake.
- It is very visible in the calling code and brings attention to the behaviour of the method.

I can think of two disadvantages of that design:

- The existence of the parameter might give users the impression that the parameter affects the return value of the method.
- It is more verbose than using an unrestricted generic return type as Peter suggests in his answer.